# What function could I use to send values to Arduino uno with node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arduino, serial-port

I have a problem, my code in Arduino allows me to send values to turn on a led with `Serial.read ()`, but when I do it with node js `port.write ()` I have tried several ways but it does not turn on the led.

**arduino code**

```
int pin = 12;
String vali="OFF";
char val;

void setup() {
  pinMode(pin,OUTPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  val = Serial.read();
  if(val == '1'){
    digitalWrite(pin,HIGH);
    vali="ON";
  }
  else if(val == '0'){
    digitalWrite(pin,LOW);
    vali="OFF";
  }
    delay(1000);
    Serial.println(" estado:"+ vali );
}
```

**js code**

```
const Serialport = require('serialport');
const readline = Serialport.parsers.Readline;
var val = 0;
const port = new Serialport('COM3', {
    baudRate: 9600
});
const parse = port.pipe(new readline({ delimiter: '\r\n' }));

port.on('open', function() {
    console.log('conect ');
});

port.write("1\r\n");
parse.write("1\r\n");

parse.on("data", (data) => {
    console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: Are you sure you are sending data to the right port?

Answer (score 0):

It is stopping because of the `delay(1000);` as it is a blocking delay and `Serial.read` isn't able to fully read data. Try removing it and adding statements like

```cpp
if(Serail.available > 0)
{
    // Then read data and afterwards turn the led on or off with delay inside here.
    // Also for 1,2  or any other numeric you can use Serial.parseInt() function
    // to read them
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).